# How to add templates in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am learning meteor framework. I am trying to render template but it throws this error:

```
Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with static-html (for target web.browser):
client/html/sidebar.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
```

my layout.html file is this:

```
<body>

    {{> sidebar}}

</body>
```

and sidebar.html file is this:

```
<template name="sidebar">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>
```

Why its not rendering on layout.html??

Answer (score 0):

Replace your body tag by a template called "layout" (for example) and make this template a layoutTemplate inside your router configuration.

```
<template name="layout">

  {{> sidebar}}

  {{> yield}}

</template>
```

With IronRouter for example:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

Comment: where will I have to add to router.configure??

Comment: Anywhere in a file in the /lib folder. I call my file "router.js". Please verify that you are using IronRouter. Projects by default use FlowRouter I believe. In that case, I don't know how to configure your router.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is that you're using the `static-html` package and not `blaze-html-templates`, which means all the template code won't be processed

Do:

```
meteor remove static-html
meteor add blaze-html-templates
```

In your project folder and see if that helps